# Cannot create property 'replyToId' when chatbot reply messages use Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I'm develop chatbot with REST use ruby on rails and emulator. When my chatbot reply messages to user, i have a problem:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ServiceError",
        "message": "Cannot create property 'replyToId' on string 'type=message&from[id]=ch1ilide7a2hm0lj3&from[name]=Bot&conversation[id]=e365an7nh78ckc8c4c&recipient[id]=default-user&recipient[name]=User&text=My+reply&replyToId=aj3d8l13dj1iik077c'"
    }
}
```

My bot receive messages

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "text": "test",
  "from": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "User"
  },
  "locale": "en-US",
  "timestamp": "2017-06-30T09:18:51.414Z",
  "channelData": {
    "clientActivityId": "1498814323988.43585210617995895.0"
  },
  "id": "f981681n6mn1i6ef",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "localTimestamp": "2017-06-30T16:18:51+07:00",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "ch1ilide7a2hm0lj3",
    "name": "Bot"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "2bc3d4ag3ekdg8f"
  },
  "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:33893"
}
```

My code when reply messages:

```
class ReplyMessagesService
  def perform params, access_token
    conversation = params['conversation']
    bot          = params['recipient']
    user         = params['from']
    activity_id  = params['id']
    service_url  = params['serviceUrl']
    url = service_url + '/v3/conversations/' + conversation['id'] + '/activities/' + activity_id
    begin
      RestClient.post url,
        {
          "type": "message",
          "from": {
            "id": bot["id"],
            "name": bot["name"],
          },
          "conversation": {
            "id": conversation["id"],
          },
          "recipient": {
            "id": user["id"],
            "name": user["name"],
          },
          "text": "My reply",
          "replyToId": activity_id,
        },
        {
          "authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
          "content_type": "application/json"
        }
    rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => e
      e.response
    end
  end
end
```

My params before bot reply messages

```
    //user
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"default-user", "name"=>"User"} permitted: false>
    //bot
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"ch1ilide7a2hm0lj3", "name"=>"Bot"} permitted: false>
    //conversation
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"b80253miifem6ie86"} permitted: false>
    //activity_id
"hk696f267j9gjdc6i"
    //service_url
"http://localhost:33893"
    //url
    "http://localhost:33893/v3/conversations/b80253miifem6ie86/activities/hk696f267j9gjdc6i"
```

please help me.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was because of the content-type header, it needs to be set **"Content-Type: application/json"**. Let me show what I was doing, I was creating a reply but setting the content-type on the request, while I needed to that on the content (although this was on C#). I'm not that proficient on Ruby, but try setting up the content type and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks! As you say, i have fixed it.